# How to prevent the Display size from scaling?

Tags: android, font-scaling

I have make the changes in the app so the fonts will scale by using the sp for the textsizes but at the same time i also want to restrict the display size to scale my app. For reference I have used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779224/how-do-i-prevent-android-device-display-size-scaling-in-my-app?noredirect=1&lq=1). But it will cause problems in some samsung devices when user changes the Resolution . e.g if user changes the resolution to HD+ screen zoom in and if user changes resolution to QWHD+ the display screen zoom out. Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks!!

Thanks!!