# How to prevent android OS from zooming my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The main screen in my app works fine when the screen zoom is set to default:

[image]

When I set the screen zoom to the maximum, layouts overlap:

[image]

I want to disable android OS from zooming my app. In other words I don't want the activity to be resizable. I tried different solutions but non of them achieves what I want.

I used this code in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="360" />
```

But the app is still zoomed but with a warning message to the user that the app may behave unexpectedly:

[image]

How can disable resizing or zooming my activity on all screens?
Plz help me.

Comment: If the user has enabled screen zoom, presumably the user *wants the screen to be zoomed*. For example, it may make the text easier to read or make small UI elements easier to tap on.

Comment: I sure know that, but I'm going to set the default icons and font of the app to a large size, which will force all views to overlap in a way that makes the app useless. Is there any way to prevent this?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779224/how-do-i-prevent-android-device-display-size-scaling-in-my-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I'm looking for an official configuration, not a work around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not prevent zooming. As CommonsWare commented, the user *wants to zoom in*.

The best thing to do in this case is making every page/layout that might not fit on a small/zoomed screen scrollable. That way, if it doesn't fit the user can just scroll down.