# Android device Display Size setting scaling app (React Native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, size, display

I've thoroughly researched the issue of preventing Android device display size scaling in my app and attempted the solution from [How-do-i-prevent-android-device-display-size-scaling-in-my-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779224/how-do-i-prevent-android-device-display-size-scaling-in-my-app).

By default, the configuration.densityDpi is set to 440. However, after manually setting the Display Size to the largest, the configuration.densityDpi value changes to 540. I implemented the provided solution code, which successfully resets the densityDpi back to 440. Despite this, the UI elements still appear as if the device is using the largest Display Size.

My app runs on Android Version 13 and has been tested on various devices, including Samsung, Honor, and Pixel. The UI components affected are 'View' and 'WebView,' and I'm not using any third-party libraries or custom components. React Native version is 0.68.2.

I'm seeking assistance in identifying what might be causing this issue and how I can effectively prevent display size scaling in my app. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!