# Weird text scaling issues in webview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have a problem in my game project. The game is based on a webview used to load an [url](http://rodoapps.ihostfull.com/gametest/) where the game is present, but it seems to have text scaling issues if you change the font size in settings, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2xcQ.png).

I can't determine where the problem is coming from, but it gets really annoying, especially if even bigger font sizes are used.

Here's the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is activity file:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        CustomWebViewClient client = new CustomWebViewClient(this);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0xfaf8ef);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://rodoapps.ihostfull.com/gametest/");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.webView.canGoBack()){
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
}

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    private Activity activity;

    public CustomWebViewClient(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request){
        return false;


    }
}
```

Sorry for my English, I am not a native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306032/16332555), I have managed to solve my problem.

The only thing different from that answer is that my use case required removing one line of code.

Here's my solution:

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.fontScale = (float) 1; //0.85 small size, 1 normal size, 1,15 big etc
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
```